# Why does Telegram not open Instagram URI links?

Tags: android, ios, uri, instagram, telegram

Why does [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(software)) open [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) URI links on Android devices?

As an example:

instagram://user?username=therock does not open on Android, but the same link works on [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS).

Comment: Also URI link tg://resolve?domain=edent can open on Android and IOS, so what the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Telegram only supports `http://`, `https://` and `tg://user?id=109780439` for inline mention. It can't open other schema for now.

You can make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport). Let them know many people needs this feature.